# How to setup FastAPI comunication with firestore through Pyrebase4

Tags: python-3.x, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, fastapi, pyrebase

I'm new in FastAPI and NoSQL databases.
I've worked with FastAPI only with relational database PostgreSQL using SQLAlchemy.
This NoSQL [example](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/nosql-databases/#import-couchbase-components)  uses couchbase, and I didn't found any info or example of using FastAPI with [Pyrebase4](https://github.com/nhorvath/Pyrebase4#authentication)

Is there a simple way to connect FastAPI with Firestore? Any information could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've opened an issue on FastAPI github asking for help: [fastapi_issue](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/2651).

It turns out that Pyrebase4 has no support for Firestore, only Realtime Database.

My option is to use [firebase_admin](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) SDK, if I want to deal with Firestore.